# SQLite - remove row with a lowest id

Tags: sqlite

How can I remove a row from a table that has lowest rowid?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  Id = (SELECT MIN(Id) FROM MyTable);
```

Answer (score 5):

In most cases like this, rowid is an indexed column. If that is the case the **much** faster solution is:

```
DELETE FROM 
  tablename
WHERE
  rowid= (SELECT rowid FROM tablename order by rowid limit 1)
```

If rowid is NOT indexed then:

```
DELETE FROM 
  tablename
WHERE
  rowid= (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM tablename)
```

I'd still test the first one as it will often be faster, even if rowid is not indexed.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM 
  tablename
WHERE
  rowid= (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM tablename)
```